# How to do "proper" MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I am a newer web developer (~1 year experience) who has just joined a new firm which uses the Umbraco CMS for a lot of the websites we develop.  At my last job, I was only exposed to WebForms so I did a little research on MVC before starting this job and did a very beginner's tutorial but I'm not sure if I'm understanding the community's "best practices" when it comes to this stuff so hopefully you guys can help me out. When it comes to the Umbraco CMS, there are components called "Macro-Scripts" which is essentially a Razor View (.CSHTML) which allows you to code a bunch of C# & HTML in a page and display this "Macro-Script" on any CMS page that you choose.

In my tutorial (which I completed well over 2 months ago), I thought I remembered reading something about never mixing conditional logic / C# with HTML, and that it's better to use Models & Controllers?  I'm a bit confused because we don't really build controllers in the first place for our websites because they are CMS pages and if they need to be anything besides Rich-Text, then we just create a "Macro-Script" and place it on the page which needs extended functionality.

What I've found in working my first month here, is that I could save a lot of time if I was able to make my code re-usable across the website, but I'm not really sure how to do that in a way that's "MVC friendly"?  Here is an example "Macro-Script" which displays a form created in the CMS, and then attempts to grab the companies "contact" information and display it underneath the form.  The example I've attached is extremely simple, but some of these Macro-Scripts that I've seen become an atrocious mess of 500+ lines with huge for-each loops, switches, and blocks of unreadable code.

Is it possible to split this type of code into a Model for use in this View?  Is there any benefit to splitting the code as opposed to having it all in the same view? (I would like to present this to my co-workers and change coding standards if there are enough benefits).  Could someone give me an example of how this would look if it were to be split-up into proper "MVC"?  If this isn't the correct place to post this type of question, please point me to a better StackExchange site. Thanks.

**Macro-Script to grab CMS Form & Company Information**

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

@*
    Model = The current page the macro is executed on
            @Model.bodyText

    Parameter = collection of parameter values passed from the macro
            @Paramter.myParam

    Library = utillity library with common methods
            @Library.NodeById(1233)
*@

@* The fun starts here *@

@{
    string formClass = "form-content";
    var configNode = Model.AncestorOrSelf().Descendants("ConfigurationContainer").FirstOrDefault();
    if (configNode != null && configNode.Id > 0)
    {
        formClass = "form-content show-address";
    }
    if (custom.Library.NodeHasPropertyAndValue(Model, "bodyText"))
    {
        <hr />
    }

    <div class="form-page contact-us">
        <div>
            <div class="@formClass">
               @Html.Raw(umbraco.library.RenderMacroContent("<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias=\"umbracoContour.RazorRenderForm\" formGuid=\""+Model.selectedForm+"\" ></?UMBRACO_MACRO>", Model.Id))
            </div>
        @if (configNode != null && configNode.Id > 0)
        {
            <address class="address-content">
                @if (custom.Library.NodeHasPropertyAndValue(configNode, "officeAddress"))
                {
                    var addressDisplay = (custom.Library.NodeHasPropertyAndValue(configNode, "officeAddress2")) ? string.Format("{0}, {1}", configNode.officeAddress, configNode.officeAddress2) : configNode.officeAddress;
                    string locationString = string.Empty;
                    string cityDisplay = (custom.Library.NodeHasPropertyAndValue(configNode, "officeCity")) ? configNode.officeCity : string.Empty,
                    stateDisplay = (custom.Library.NodeHasPropertyAndValue(configNode, "officeState")) ? configNode.officeState : string.Empty,
                    zipDisplay = (custom.Library.NodeHasPropertyAndValue(configNode, "officeZip")) ? configNode.officeZip : string.Empty;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityDisplay) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stateDisplay))
                    {
                        locationString = string.Format("<br />{0}, {1} {2}", cityDisplay, stateDisplay, zipDisplay);
                    }

                    @addressDisplay@Html.Raw(locationString)

                }
                @if (custom.Library.NodeHasPropertyAndValue(configNode, "officePhone"))
                {
                    <br /><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> @configNode.officePhone
                }
                @if (custom.Library.NodeHasPropertyAndValue(configNode, "officeFax"))
                {
                    <br /><i class="fa fa-fax"></i> @configNode.officeFax
                }
                @if (custom.Library.NodeHasPropertyAndValue(configNode, "officeEmail"))
                {
                    <br /><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <a href="mailto:@configNode.officeEmail">@configNode.officeEmail</a>
                }
            </address>
        }
        </div>
    </div>

    if (custom.Library.NodeHasPropertyAndValue(Model, "lowerText"))
    {
        @Html.Raw(Model.lowerText)
    }
}
```

Comment: As much as it pains me to say cause you've clearly put a lot of thought into this question, it's too broad.  You're basically asking for the crooks of how to do MVC. :(.  One thing I will say is only basic logic should be in your `.chtml` view.  You should pass and object that has already been processed which contains the minimum values required to display the page, it should require no further processing other than basic looping (such as foreach loops).  Any processing should be done in your controller before it's passed to the view.  I hope this helps!

Comment: CodeReview might be a good SE site to try. Your code is working, you're just looking for feedback and (potentially) better approaches.

Comment: As this question specifically relate to Umbraco, which has it's own "flavour" of MVC to a degree, the question is not as broad as it may first appear - see my answer below regarding ways to clean this up etc.  It seems though that you need to review the Umbraco implementation documentation on http://our.umbraco.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to use Umbraco terminology here which at first glance may not seem like Asp.Net MVC:

You need to ask yourself - do you need to use a Macro?  If you're embedding the Macro directly into a Template, then the chances are you can either use a PartialView (found in /Views/Partials just like standard MVC) or just incorporate the layout directly in the Template (found in /Views).

First thing you should do is review the Umbraco Documentation (take note of the version of Umbraco each topic targets - there's still Umbraco 4.10+ specific content there):

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/

Regarding splitting out the logic:

**Code First Models:**
Take a look at [Umbraco Ditto](https://github.com/leekelleher/umbraco-ditto) - it's a way to use Models with the Umbraco IPublishedContent; there's quite a bit of documentation for it so it should be fairly straightforward to implement.

**Controllers:** 
You can use ASP.Net MVC Controllers to back your partials and provide models; you need to inherit from `SurfaceControllers` though:

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Routing/surface-controllers

**Rendering Macros**:  Don't use `@Html.Raw(umbraco.library.RenderMacroContent(..))` - it's pretty much deprecated.  The standard way to do it now is to use `@Umbraco.RenderMacro()`.  So this:

```
@Html.Raw(umbraco.library.RenderMacroContent("<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias=\"umbracoContour.RazorRenderForm\" formGuid=\""+Model.selectedForm+"\" ></?UMBRACO_MACRO>", Model.Id))
```

becomes

```
@Umbraco.RenderMacro("FormsRenderForm", new { FormGuid = Model.selectedForm })
```

**Final thoughts:**

Personally, I wouldn't use Macros to generate your content unless you need to allow the backoffice user to embed the functionality into a page and provide parameters.  If that's not the case, you're better off implementing the layout either directly in the Template or a Partial View.